# Should I use vue cli when working on just a page

Tags: vue-cli

At work, I'm tasked to work on just a page of our website using vue.js. Does it make sense to use vue cli?  Our website doesn't use vue.js yet and I'm just asked to use it on a page.  What I do is just create the page and send it to my teammate and he will integrate it to our production build.